# Getting the following error while uploading the image using html

Tags: angularjs, blob

Refused to load the image 'blob:http://localhost:1821/37fbc038-a2de-4fba-94cf-7168e0c22a83' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src * data: https: 'self'". Note that '*' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches `self`'s scheme. The scheme 'blob:' must be added explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to apply middleware on your server side, if you are using NodeJS you can add the following in your route file: `app.use(express.static('public'));`